# How to schedule task in AWS Sagemaker to run training job

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have an optimization code running in sagemaker. I want to run the code in every 1 hr. How can I schedule the run in sagemaker?. I do not want to call model endpoint, but I want to run the whole code in every 1 hr.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways you can schedule to run training job

1. Call [create-training-job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateTrainingJob.html) API from a scheduled Lambda function or a [CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) .
2. Trigger [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connectors-sagemaker.html) from [CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-target.html) to schedule tasks in SageMaker